# CircleCI: Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

Tags: angular, hadoop-yarn, circleci, node-sass

Before I start, we are using YARN as a package manager, docker and CircleCI.
I worked on a project locally and wanted to commit it to the master branch. In the building workflow the following error occurred.

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
echo $SHELL
export NVM_DIR="/opt/circleci/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
yarn run grunt build-wordpress && sudo chown -R circleci:circleci output && yarn run grunt build-wp-extras
/bin/bash
yarn run v1.19.1
$ /home/circleci/tsworkspace/cns/wordpress-multisite-relaunch/node_modules/.bin/grunt build-wordpress
Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Missing binding /home/circleci/tsworkspace/cns/wordpress-multisite-relaunch/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
>> Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 10.x
>> 
>> Found bindings for the following environments:
>>   - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 12.x
>> 
>> This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
>> Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
Warning: Task "build-wordpress" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
error Command failed with exit code 3.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Exited with code 3
```

Using npm rebuild node-sass even with force locally, doesn't solve the problem. Is is it a problem with Docker? Could the solution be to rebuild node-sass before building for the master?
If yes, how do I do that. 
Thanks already for your answers in advance folks!